# Custom Google Search with 'search web' and search 'my site' radio buttons

Tags: search, google-custom-search

I have some experience setting up Google CSEs. I have a request to set up a CSE with an option to 'search the web' or just search the site.

I thought it would be very simple, but iver yet to find an example or tutorial.

Can anyone point me in the right direction and or give me an example of a Google CSE that has a radio button (any button, or input for that matter) to search 'the web' or just the current site which the CSE is set up to do.

Thanks,
Jesse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create the custom search engine; the radio buttons are automatically there. Just go to http://www.google.com/cse/, click the create button, and then fill out each section that is relevant to you (probably everything except for advanced, promotions, synonyms, and look+feel at the moment). Note that the radio buttons are not on the main search page, but may be found on all the results pages.

**Edit**
In the "Basics" tab, select "Search only included sites" under "Preferences". Under "Look and feel", select the default style. The search results page should show a radio button with the first one labeled with the name of your search engine and the second button labeled "Web Search".

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Sorry it does not seem the 'search web' option is on either the main nor the results page.

To confirm, I know how to make a Google CSE, i *need to have the option to search the entire web or just my site* as options.